# Form validation script issues

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have two scripts at the top of a form.  The first one works *perfectly* and provides a client-end validation for email addresses.  The second one doesn't work at all, (even if I change my onsubmit to JUST that function name).  I'm sure I'm missing something totally obvious.  I can set it up to server-end validation, but the API with the software I'm using totally nukes the form entries, so I'm trying to avoid that.

```
  <script>
     function validateForm()
     {
        var x = document.forms["form5"]["element_1"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length)
        {
           alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
           return false;
        }
     }
  </script>
  <script>
     function validateMisc()
     {
        if (document.forms["form5"]["element_27"].value !== null && 
            document.forms["form5"]["element_57"].value == null)
        {
           alert("Misc details are required if a value is entered for Misc Projects.");
           return false;
        }
     }
  </script>
```

Here is my form action command currently.

```
<form 
   action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" 
   name="form5" 
   action="demo_form.asp" 
   onsubmit="return validateForm() && validateMisc();" 
   method="POST">
```

Comment: If `document.forms["form5"]["element_27"]` represents and input then maybe check against `""` and not againts `null`

Answer (score 0):

if inputs with name="element_27" and name="element_57" exist they will never be null. They could be empty string. .value === '' and .value !== ''

Comment: This worked in conjunction with FoxNos's solution.  However, now it's still submitting the form.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

Change your form like

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" name="form5" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST">
```

Then i would revise the javascript like:

```
<script>
function validateForm()  
{
var x=document.forms["form5"]["element_1"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
   alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
   return false;
}
else 
{
//If the email is valid, lets call the other function
   validateMisc()
}
}
</script>


<script>
function validateMisc()
    {


    if (document.forms["form5"]["element_27"].value !== null && document.forms["form5"]["element_57"].value == null)

{

    alert("Misc details are required if a value is entered for Misc Projects.");

    return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

I personally didn't check the code, so it could not work. In this case, my apologizes